# How to change code to avoid unreacheable error in python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Wrote this telegram bot. Pycharm gives me error 'The last two lines are unreacheable'. What is the solution? Without 'while true' part code isn't working

```
import telebot
import gspread
import datetime
import schedule
import time


bot_token = '____'
googlesheet_id = '___'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='.json')
sh = gc.open('___')
wks = sh.worksheet('sheet1')
CHAT_ID = "___"


def check_date():
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_date_string = current_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
    sh = gc.open('___')
    search_data = wks.find(current_date_string)
    list = wks.row_values(search_data.row)
    bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, '%s expires today' % (list[0]))
schedule.every().day.at("12:00:00").do(check_date)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the *exact* error you're seeing? I doubt PyCharm would throw such an error as you've indicated currently.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the perfect question and how to create a [Minimal , Complete and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @esqew "This code is unreachable: № of line"

Comment: The `while` loop never exits.  Thus, the `bot.polling` line will never be reached.  What are you trying to do here?  You can't run two infinite loops at the same time.  Perhaps you need a thread for the scheduler stuff.

Comment: @TimRoberts i understand problem with while but didn’t find any solution. I want my code running on particular date. How to write that thread?

Comment: FIRST, check to see whether "telebot" has any date/time callback functions.  If they can call you once a minute or once an hour, then you can do the timing thing yourself.  Otherwise, you will have to put the schedule loop in a function and use `Threading.thread` to run that function in its own thread.

Answer (score 1):

You (roughly) wrote

```
def check_date():
    ...

while True:
    do_thing_one()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_thing_two()
```

The last two lines, testing `__name__` and doing thing two, are useless, they will never execute.
Why are they unreachable?
Because of the thing one `while` loop,
which never lets us get down to attempt thing two.

---

Notice that the `while` loop is not part of
the `check_date` function.
If you were to indent that section four spaces,
then the `check_date` function would never exit
but we *would* be able to do thing two.

---

It does not appear that thing two,
the `.polling()` call, relates to `check_date`.
Perhaps there is some unseen linkage behind
the scenes.

Comment: how to solve this?

Comment: @Tim_Roberts was fairly eloquent on this topic: "You can't run two infinite loops at the same time." Either event loop one will need to convince the 2nd loop to schedule its tasks, or vice versa. Consult the thread scheduler docs for details.